# Text Editor with Bootstrap elements

Tags: text, ckeditor, editor, rows

I currently developing a back office for my web site.
to change the content of a page I install CKEditor, but the problem is that it does not support bootstrap like "class rows".
someone can help me to have a text generator with the functionality of this bootstrap option.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to disable the advanced content filtering.

simply set  CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent to `true`. in your config.js file 
or